# Paste the value start from the range until the last row while using DO WHILE LOOP dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have sheets with data that has 56 rows all and I'm using DO WHILE LOOP in dates by week. By using this `Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` this code it will start paste the value start from Range("A57") because A57 is the last available row. I want to paste start from A3 not in A57

This is the code.

```
    Dim d As Date
    d = DateValue("31-dec-22")
    Dim LastDate As Date
    Dim StartDate As Date

    Do
     k = k + 7
     LastDate = DateAdd("d", k, d)
     StartDate = LastDate - 6
     Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = StartDate & " - " & LastDate
    Loop While LastDate <= CDate("1-jan-24")`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim d As Date
d = DateValue("31-dec-22")
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

Do
 k = k + 7
 LastDate = DateAdd("d", k, d)
 StartDate = LastDate - 6
 Range("A3").Offset(i, 0) = StartDate & " - " & LastDate
 i = i + 1
Loop While LastDate <= CDate("1-jan-24")
```